# Safari prevent auto play of video.js player

Tags: javascript, vue.js, safari, vuejs2, video.js

On my site I have vue-video-player which use video.js library. On mobile chrome at samsung galaxy s9 it autoplay correctly but it doesn't autoplay on mobile safari at iphone 7.

HTML is:

```
<video-player  class="video-player-box"
               id="player"
               ref="videoPlayer"
               :options="playerOptions"
               @ended="onPlayerEnded($event)">
</video-player>
```

and in my script tag:

```
data() {
    return {
        playerOptions: {
            muted: true,
            autoplay: true,
            controls: false,
            sources: [{
                type: "video/mp4",
                src: "https://res.cloudinary.com/dlqvkenro/video/upload/v1544320787/gvnn.mp4"
            }],
            poster: "/static/images/author.jpg",
        }
    }
},
```

Actually on safari when I click sound icon video start playing but I want it to start automatically when user enter page.

I added code to programically start player:

```
mounted() {
    this.player.play()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('play succseed');
        })
        .catch(() => {
            alert('safari prevent player');
        });
},
```

and actually in safari alert appears. Is there anyting I can do to win against apple?

[Demo](http://activeyachtclub.co.uk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at this here https://blog.videojs.com/autoplay-best-practices-with-video-js/

I hop it help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with just using a `<video>` tag in my vue component. I was able to get it to auto play but had to reload the html for it to work. Perhaps there is something you can use below...

```
<template>
<div class="video-wrapper">
    <video class="video" playsinline muted autoplay loop>
        <source src="loopedVideo.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
</div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
name: 'Video',
mounted() {
    // Start looped video.
    let isSafari = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    let video = document.querySelector('.video');
    if (isSafari && video) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // werid fix for safari
            document.querySelector('.video-wrapper').innerHTML = video.outerHTML;
        }, 100);
    }
}
}
</script>
```